# Can't get Pretty Printers to work for debugging Nim code in Codium (VSCode) with GDB (nim-gdb.py)

Tags: gdb, nim-lang, vscodium

I tried to debug my `Nim` code in `VSCodium` with `Native Debug` extension and `GDB`. But I can't get the Pretty Printers to work properly.

Here is my `launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug x64 Linux",
            "type": "gdb",
            "gdbpath": "nim-gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "target": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/debug/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "valuesFormatting": "prettyPrinters",
            "arguments": "",
            "debugger_args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The `nim-gdb.py` is located under `/usr/tools/` and will be loaded.

Here is the debugger output of the debugging session in VSCodium. It seem's that the `nim-gdb.py` is loaded successfully. But neither in the variables panel nor in the debugging console the values are formatted right. The `str`-variable is still missing and depending on where I set a breakpoint the values are often marked as `<optimized out>`

[Debugger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx4sU.png)

The Program was compiled with the following parameters:

`nim c --outdir:"bin/debug" --debugger:native --opt:none test.nim`

Compiler Version:

```
Nim Compiler Version 1.6.6 [Linux: amd64]
Compiled at 2022-05-22
Copyright (c) 2006-2021 by Andreas Rumpf
```

I know the gdb package needs to be compiled with python enabled. In my package manager is python as a dependency listed.

Is there something more I should care about?

References:

- https://internet-of-tomohiro.netlify.app/nim/gdb.en.html
- https://github.com/jasonprogrammer/nim-debug-example